# Prove $a \equiv b \pmod{p-1}$ if $g^a \equiv g^b \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Let $g$ be a primitive root for $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Suppose that $x = a$ and $x = b$ are both integer solutions to the congruence $g^x \equiv h \pmod{p}$. Prove that $a \equiv b \pmod{p-1}$.

I'm at a loss for where to even start here.

Comment: You know that $g^a\equiv g^b$, right? What is $g^{b-a}$?

Comment: $g^{b-a} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ I see that. Where does that get me?

Comment: Ah, Fermat's Little Theorem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $g$ is a primitive root means that if $g^x\equiv 1 \mod p$ then $p-1|x$. From your condition, one has $g^a\equiv g^b \mod p$, or $g^{a-b}\equiv 1\mod p$. Thus $(p-1)|(a-b)$, or $a\equiv b \mod (p-1)$.

Comment: How do you get $g^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \implies (p-1) \mid k$?

Comment: Ah, from there use Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: How do you define a primitive root? I guess it is defined as follows. $g$ is called a primitive root if it is a generator of the cyclic group $\textbf{F}_p^*$. Since $\textbf{F}_p^*$ is cyclic group of order $p-1$, thus the order of a generator must be $p-1$.

Comment: I don't think Fermat's little theorem gives you that. That should follow from the definition of primitive root.

Comment: That's even simpler than Fermat's Little Theorem. Thank you!